# Residual SQL Server 2000 Objects When Restoring DB to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, database-migration

I've performed a RESTORE DATABASE command to restore an SQL Server 2000 database on SQL Server 2008. The script ran and showed several messages showing the DB being upgraded. What I've noticed is that (seemingly) legacy database objects from SQL Server 2000 have been migrated to the SQL 2008 DB.

For example, there are stored procedures whose name starts with `dbo.dt_` in both the Stored Procedure and System Stored Procedure folders when viewing the DB in Management Studio. There was also the table `dbo.dtproperties` listed under tables.

Is it safe to drop these objects? These objects aren't in a DB created in SQL 2008 itself, so I'm thinking yes. But I'd like to make sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those objects exist for database diagrams.  If you don't have any database diagrams in your database that you care about, then it is fine to delete those objects.